# Have javascript toggled on with screen load, and then with click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have a menu that has a script function where a click toggles on a different background color of that link until another link is clicked:

```
    $(function() {
       $(".button").click(function() {
         $(this).css('background-color', '#555');
         $(".button").not($(this)).css('background-color', '');

       });
    });
```

I would like this link:

```
    <a class="button main" href="background.html">Main</a>
```

to have the background color toggled on with page load, but retain the toggling function as from before.

This is the rest of the HTML:

```
    <a class="button main" href="background.html">Main</a>
    <a class="button" href="text-1.htm">Text 1</a>
    <a class="button" href="text-2.htm">Text 2</a>
    <a class="button" href="text-3.htm">Text 3</a>
    <a class="button" href="text-4.htm">Text 4</a>
    <a class="button" href="text-5.htm">Text 5</a>
    <a class="button" href="text-6.htm">Text 6</a>
    <a class="button" href="text-7.htm">Text 7</a>
    <a class="button" href="text-8.htm">Text 8</a>
    <a class="button" href="text-9.htm">Text 9</a>
    <a class="button" href="text-10.htm">Text 10</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('.main').css('background-color', '#555');

    $(".button").click(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#555');
        $(".button").not($(this)).css('background-color', '');
    });
});
```

You can simply put style on main after the document is ready.

Better Option:

CSS

```
.main { background: #555 }
```

JS

```
$(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".button").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.main').removeClass('main');
        $(this).addClass('main');
    });
});
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/rv68enu6/

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks, @HermLuna!

Comment: Glad it helped. Check the fiddle.